# Sonar to import unit test coverage for both Java and JavaScripts

Tags: sonarqube

Our project uses Maven as the build tool and we are using Sonar to track quality. JUnit tests are executed by SureFire and the results are displayed in Sonar. We also have lots of javascripts code and for which we are using Jasmine to generate unit test reports, but I don't know the way to import this Jasmine data to sonar.

Comment: Here are more information related to this. I'm able to generate total-coverage.dat file but when I execute the mvn sonar:sonar it only gives me the lines of code but not the unit test coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You should not confuse test results with coverage.

- The SonarQube JavaScript plugin does not import test results: [this feature was dropped](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Unit+Tests+Execution+Reports+Import).
- It can [import coverage reports](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import) which use the LCOV format.